# Spring Data Elasticsearch returning empty aggregation buckets

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

I'm using the following Spring Boot 2.0.6.RELEASE and Sppring Data Elasticsearch 3.0.11.RELEASE.

The Elasticsearch cluster is version 6.8.5

I've written some Java code to perform a query with aggregation against an index, as follows:

```
QueryBuilder bools = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(matchQuery("zip-code", 90402))
                                          .must(matchQuery("zip-plus-4", 2411));

AggregationBuilder streetAggregation = AggregationBuilders.terms("street").field("street.keyword").size(10000);

SearchRequestBuilder searchRequestBuilder = new SearchRequestBuilder(elasticsearchClient, SearchAction.INSTANCE)
                .setIndices("pallc_index") //
                .setTypes("pallc") //
                .setQuery(bools) //
                .setSize(0) //
                .setExplain(true) //
                .addAggregation(streetAggregation);

log.debug("srb : {}", searchRequestBuilder);

SearchResponse searchResponse = searchRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();

log.debug("Search Response : {}", searchResponse);
```

The debug line towards the end of this snippet that logs the query, dumps the following Elasticsearch query:

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {
          "match" : {
            "zip-code" : {
              "query" : 90402,
              "operator" : "OR",
              "prefix_length" : 0,
              "max_expansions" : 50,
              "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
              "lenient" : false,
              "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
              "boost" : 1.0
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match" : {
            "zip-plus-4" : {
              "query" : 2411,
              "operator" : "OR",
              "prefix_length" : 0,
              "max_expansions" : 50,
              "fuzzy_transpositions" : true,
              "lenient" : false,
              "zero_terms_query" : "NONE",
              "boost" : 1.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "disable_coord" : false,
      "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  },
  "explain" : true,
  "aggregations" : {
    "street" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "street.keyword",
        "size" : 10000,
        "min_doc_count" : 1,
        "shard_min_doc_count" : 0,
        "show_term_doc_count_error" : false,
        "order" : [
          {
            "_count" : "desc"
          },
          {
            "_term" : "asc"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I execute this query using Postman (or curl) then I get the following response from Elasticsearch:

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 18,
        "max_score": 0.0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "street": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "20TH",
                    "doc_count": 18
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

As can be seen, there is an aggregation bucket that is returned for "street" with a key of "20TH".

If I try to inspect the response from the Java code, I can see the aggregation but the bucket is empty.

This is the log line relating to the Search Response debug in the Java code:

```
15:32:53.144 DEBUG [http-nio-20004-exec-1] com.smoltech.service.PallcAddressService - Search Response : {"took":8,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":0.0,"hits":[]},"aggregations":{"street":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[]}}}
```

One other thing that's odd is that in the result from the Java code (running the same query essentially as Postman) it's showing 0 hits whereas Postman is returning 18 hits.

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt - check your configuration, then check it again! I realised I was using the wrong Spring profile when the Java code was executing which meant I was pointing at the wrong ES cluster!

My edit re: 0 hits vs. 18 hits was the clue I needed...